# How do I use Flask.route with Flask

Tags: python, flask

A brief introduction to the directory structure is as follows:
[image]

`__init__.py` contain the application factory.

page.py

```
from app import app


# a simple page that says hello
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

app.py

```
from flaskr import create_app

app = create_app()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I start the server and go to the '/hello', it says 404.
What's the problem?

Comment: You need to define the method type as well. Like `@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET'])`

Comment: @stud3nt Normally it should default to `GET` if no methods are defined.
@Mercy Gainsborough should it not be `from flask import create_app` in your `app.py` ?

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, I didn't understand. What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short solution which should run.

page.py

```
from flaskr import app

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello'
```

__index__.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from flaskr import page
```

app.py

```
from flaskr import app
```

To run this you just need to define a Environment Variable on the Commandline like this:

```
export FLASK_APP=microblog.py
```

And then run it with

```
flask run
```

Comment: `from flaskr import page` should be in app.py, not __init__.py

Answer (score 0):

The way you have structured your code is not right. That's the reason you are not able to access your "/hello" API.

Let's assume that you run the app.py file. In this case, you haven't imported page.py right? So, how will the app.py know that there is a route defined in page.py?

Alternatively, let's assume you run page.py. In this case, when you do an "from app import app" , the main definition does not get executed. Here too, the route will now be present, but the app will not be run, thereby you will be unable to access your API.

The simplest solution would be to combine the contents of app.py and page.py into a single file.

Comment: Maybe I can use Buleprint. But I want to use app that instance of Flask.